# Approximating an Integral for Numerical Computation

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I have a program that involves computing a definite integral many times, and have been struggling to find a way to do so quickly. The integrals I need to solve are of the following form:

$$\int_{a(r)}^{b}f(x)g(x-r)dx$$

where I need to compute the integral for many different values of r.  At the moment I am stuck figuring at a programming solution and instead am looking for a way to mathematically approximate this integral.  Does anyone have any ideas/tricks/resources?  If it helps, the function g is a lognormal pdf, so I am actually taking the expected value of function f.

Thanks!

EDITED:

Thank you to everyone who has commented so far.  A few people have asked about including additional information about the problem.

$a(r)$ is the root of the following equation:
$$\theta*(a-\theta)^2-\frac{1-f(r+a-\theta)}{f(r+a-\theta)}$$
where $\theta $ and $r$ are parameters

$f(x)$ is equal to the following:
$$f(x)=Pr(\sum z*I(z)>r)$$
where $z$ is a random variable with a lognormal distribution, and $I(z)$ is the indicator function equal to 1 when $z>a(r)$

$g(x)$ is the pdf of a lognormal distribution

This is complicated and very specific problem, which is why I at first looked for general ways to approximate the integral, but I hope the additional information is helpful. Thanks again for all your input.

Comment: More details about the functions involved will likely be very helpful. Not to me, but to someone who knows about numerical methods and such.

Comment: As I said below in a more complete "answer" which is not yet an answer, post your functions.  Better yet, post a link to your code on stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the latest snippet of information from you, you are just summing the function at multiple equidistant sample points and multiplying by h. That is incredibly bad because the error is proportional to h.

Simply summing using trapezoidal should do it:

$integ = h*(f(a) + f(b)) * .5 +  \dots \text{sum the rest}$

Then, to dramatically reduce the number of slices needed, use first stage Romberg:

$I1 = \text{// compute using trapezoidal with n slices}$

$I2 = \text{// compute using same, 2n slices.}$

$$R1 = \frac{(4I2 - I1)}{3};  \text{// error is now proportional to } h^4 $$

You keep doubling the number of slices, and stop when

$$ |R2 - R1| < eps$$

where eps is the absolute error you want, or

$$\left|\frac{(R2-R1)}{R2}\right| < eps$$

relative error is safer if your answers can be near zero.
You can confirm this by telling everyone a before and after.  How many slices are you using with the current method, and how many once you switch over?

It sounds like you have a single function $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.  If that is true, simply post the functions so that everyone can look at them. It's much simpler than you talking about them.  If it's not true, at least post an example of both functions.

Give an example of a and b for the specific example.  And most important, what accuracy do you need?

You claim to be getting an answer in 15ms and need more like 1.  I have written numerical integration routines in C++ which varied by a factor of 4 based on implementation, so optimization alone won't get you there.  But with 4 CPUs operating in parallel, that alone could easily solve your problem because this problem is almost completely CPU-based. Just split the loop in OpenMP.  If you are writing the code in anything but a compiled, statically typed language, then that is your solution. For example, if you were using python, you could gain a factor of 100 just by switching to C.

I realize that the implementation details are a bit off topic here.

I would recommend one of two approaches: either trapezoidal (2nd order) with Romberg (stage 1 will give you $h^4$, and step 2 will give you $h^6$.

Or Gaussian Quadrature, 3rd order, giving $h^6$ accuracy with 3 points.

Since your function is some sort of distribution, it may be that you have too big of a tail to numerically integrate efficiently.  In that case you need to first transform the limits to a finite form.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I posted the functions above, but I'm not sure they are helpful and in the case for $f(x)$, I actually use an approximation of it through interpolation.  My code is written in Python, but I'm using the Numba library to increase the speed of the loops (it is a just-in-time compiling library). However, I am thinking about implementing some of the code in Cython to see if I can get any more speed.  Could you recommend any sources on how to "first transform the limits to a finite form"?

Comment: Almost certainly, the tail is the problem. If you had a normal distribution it would decay to nothing by 10 sigma and you could just ignore it.

I will try to find a reference on the transformation of integral bounds.  As I recall, you need a change of variable, for example u=1/x, so that 1/inf is zero. That of course turns the zero into infinity, but you split into two regions. You integrate the tail by starting at some fixed a which becomes 1/a and the other end is inf, which becomes 0. Your integral for the tail becomes [0, 1/a] but you have to do a transformation to get the right area.

Comment: I see.  Although I am integrating definite integrals here, so the tail may not be as big of an issue.  But it seems like I should look closely at the region be integrating.  Thank you.

Comment: what method of integration are you using?

Comment: At the moment I am using a simple Riemann sum since it is the fastest to implement.

Comment: Do you mean you are equally weighting all your sample points? That's your problem right there.  In order to get anything like sufficient accuracy you need way too many slices.

I am going to edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not give much details about the analytical expressions of functions f(x) and g(x-r), I should admit (?) that the analytical integration cannot be performed [if you post your expressions, I shall have a look at the problem of the analytical integration]. Then, the only solution left is numerical integration. There are a lot of methods which are available for point values integration                                                  (see for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton-Cotes_formulas - higher orders are available). Otherwise, use a Runge-Kutta method                                         (see for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge-Kutta_methods).
All these methods are easy to implement and they are quite fast.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  There is no way to analytically integrate the product of f and g.  If it is is helpful, f=1-F(Z(r)), where F is the cdf for the random variable Z, which has a complicated form that I must approximate. And as I stated before, g is the lognormal pdf

Comment: @shadowprice. Then, you can find a bunch of efficient numerical methods (fast, accurate, reliable,..).

Comment: I know that there are host of numerical methods, but for my purposes, they are not fast enough.  For example, with my particular problem common quadrature methods will take around 15 ms to compute; I am looking for a method that will take less than 1 ms.  Basically, the function is difficult to compute, which slows down the numerical integration.  That is why I was hoping to instead find an approximation to the functions that might possible be quicker to then use existing numerical methods

Comment: @shadowprice. Be careful ! You can find a good approximation of your function. But this does not imply a good accuracy for the integral. This is a typical problem.